# java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00936: missing expression after adding TO_CHAR

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jdbc

I want to get the DOB as a string using jdbc. So I updated my simple sql query to have TO_CHAR as below

```
select TO_CHAR(e.birthdt,'yyyy-mm-dd') as DOB,e.* from employee e where e.id = ?
```

However it fails at line#2 below

```
    prepStmt.setLong(1,Id);
    ResultSet rs = prepStmt.executeQuery();
```

with `java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00936: missing expression`
What am I missing? I wanted to get the DOB as below

```
String dob = rs.getString("DOB");
```

Comment: And Then how do I get its value since I can't do `rs.getString("DOB")` anymore?

Comment: It's hard to tell what you've done wrong when we can't see your table structure, but try getting your query working in your SQL client first (using a number instead of the ?).  Once it works, then put it into your Java program.  Also, the `as` keyword is optional, but just fine - it's not the cause of your issue.

Comment: There’s always `String dob = rs.getDate("birthdt").toLocalDate().toString();`, for a simple `select * from employee e where e.id = ?` query.  That assumes the date of birth is never null, of course.

Comment: You should return a DATE value as a string to begin with. Use `select e.birthdt as dob, e.* ...` then use `rs.getObject("DOB", LocalDate.class)`. The query itself looks correct, so chances are, you messed up the query string in Java somehow. Print the SQL string from within your Java class before running it, then run that exact query with a SQL client (replacing the ? with a proper value)

Comment: Your error message is a syntax error with your SQL statement. Are you sure it's exactly as you shared here? You get it when you start a clause but don't complete it. There's a number of small changes to your statement that would have caused the error: removing the date format but keeping the comma (`to_char(e.birthdt , ) `), by not including the filter but still including the `where` keyword, by having a trailing comma in your select list.